# Kafka 0.10.1.0 change offset time

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, consumer

Elasticsearch pipeline set up with Kafka cluster between 2 logstash instances.
I need to reset the offset back 12 hours for a topic and start the consumer again.

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list  kfkserver:9092 --topic topicname --time 1488153601000
```

which returns `topicname:0:3730858`

1488153601000 <- 2017-02-27 00:00:01 in milliseconds

How can I set the offset time?

Comment: You cannot set the offset time. Maybe this helps: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling It's WIP to add a tool to manipulate offsets. Right now, you need to use a `KafkaConsumer` and build your own tool to manipulate committed offsets.

Comment: Ok but even without the time based offset. How could one move the offset back for a partition ?

Comment: As mentioned, there is no tool for this. You would need to do this via `KafkaConsumer#seek()` manually in your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 0.10.x and don't have the awesome offset management tool that was added in 0.11, there's a hack to use kafka-console-consumer.sh to change a consumer group's offset.  This only works with the numeric offset though, not the timestamp.

First, stop whatever process is running that's using that consumer.  Clean shutdown is best.  Then, run a command that looks like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 \
    --topic my-topic \
    --partition 1 \
    --consumer-property group.id=my-consumer-group \
    --max-messages 0 \
    --offset 12345
```

`--max-messages 0` is important here; setting it to any other value, including 1, will consume that many messages and then commit the current **latest offset** in that topic/partition.  This must be a bug in the console consumer.

Next, check your work with kafka-consumer-groups.sh:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 \
    --group my-consumer-group \
    --describe
```